# Lookup substring in map, case-insensitive

Tags: java, string, hashmap

I wrote a small lexer that transforms a charbuffer into a stream of tokens. One type of tokens are identifiers, which can either be "raw" or a keyword. To test for the latter, I have a map populated with all keywords.

```
Map<String, MyType> lookup = new HashMap<>();
lookup.put("RETURN", KEYWORD_RETURN);
[...]
```

The map is populated with all uppercase strings.

Now, what I get from my input charbuffer is simply an offset and the length, where I can find my identifier (which needn't be in uppercase there).

The obvious solution looks somewhat like this.

```
bool lookupIdentifier(CharBuffer buffer, int offset, int length, Map<String, MyType> lookupTable) {
    int current = buffer.position();
    buffer.rewind();
    String toCheck = buffer.subSequence(offset, offset + length).toString().toUpperCase();
    buffer.position(current);
    return lookupTable.containsKey(toCheck);
}
```

There are around 50 entries in the map. Is a `TreeMap` with a case-insensitive comparator a good alternative to the O(1) `HashMap` lookup?

What I dislike about my approach is that the creation of the `toCheck` string allocates. Is there a way to reuse the substring in the `CharBuffer` for lookup?

Comment: The key of your map is a String. Whether or not you use `toCheck`, a String will somewhere be used. Just because you don't store it in a variable does not mean it is not there. Although, imo, it is cleaner to use a variable.

Comment: @HarshalParekh Can you give a source for the O(1) claim? The javadoc for TreeMap states "This implementation provides guaranteed log(n) time cost for the containsKey, get, put and remove operations."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can avoid expensive string construction by using a `CharBuffer` as key type:

```
Map<CharBuffer, MyType> lookup = new TreeMap<>(Comparator
    .comparingInt(CharBuffer::remaining)
    .thenComparing((cb1,cb2) -> {
        for(int p1 = cb1.position(), p2 = cb2.position(); p1 < cb1.limit(); p1++, p2++) {
            char c1 = cb1.get(p1), c2 = cb2.get(p2);
            if(c1 == c2) continue;
            c1 = Character.toUpperCase(c1);
            c2 = Character.toUpperCase(c2);
            if(c1 != c2) return Integer.compare(c1, c2);
        }
        return 0;
    }));
lookup.put(CharBuffer.wrap("RETURN"), MyType.KEYWORD_RETURN);
```

```
boolean lookupIdentifier(
    CharBuffer buffer, int offset, int length, Map<CharBuffer, MyType> lookupTable) {

    int currentPos = buffer.position(), currLimit = buffer.limit();
    buffer.clear().position(offset).limit(offset + length);
    boolean result = lookupTable.containsKey(buffer);
    buffer.clear().position(currentPos).limit(currLimit);
    return result;
}
```

The comparator uses a cheap length comparison before performing a case insensitive character comparison. This assumes that you stay with keywords like `RETURN`, which have a simple case mapping.

For a map with 50 keywords, using log₂ comparisons for a lookup might still yield reasonable performance. Mind that each comparison stops at the first mismatch.

---

You can use hashing with a dedicated wrapper object:

```
final class LookupKey {
    final CharBuffer cb;
    LookupKey(CharBuffer cb) {
        this.cb = cb;
    }
    @Override public int hashCode() {
        int code = 1;
        for(int p = cb.position(); p < cb.limit(); p++) {
            code = Character.toUpperCase(cb.get(p)) + code * 31;
        }
        return code;
    }
    @Override public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(!(obj instanceof LookupKey)) return false;
        final LookupKey other = (LookupKey)obj;
        CharBuffer cb1 = this.cb, cb2 = other.cb;
        if(cb1.remaining() != cb2.remaining()) return false;
        for(int p1 = cb1.position(), p2 = cb2.position(); p1 < cb1.limit(); p1++, p2++) {
            char c1 = cb1.get(p1), c2 = cb2.get(p2);
            if(c1 == c2) continue;
            c1 = Character.toUpperCase(c1);
            c2 = Character.toUpperCase(c2);
            if(c1 != c2) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

```
Map<LookupKey, MyType> lookup = new HashMap<>();
lookup.put(new LookupKey(CharBuffer.wrap("RETURN")), MyType.KEYWORD_RETURN);
```

```
boolean lookupIdentifier(
    CharBuffer buffer, int offset, int length, Map<LookupKey, MyType> lookupTable) {

    int currentPos = buffer.position(), currLimit = buffer.limit();
    buffer.clear().position(offset).limit(offset + length);
    boolean result = lookupTable.containsKey(new LookupKey(buffer));
    buffer.clear().position(currentPos).limit(currLimit);
    return result;
}
```

The construction of a lightweight object like the `LookupKey`, which unlike `String` construction doesn’t need to copy character contents, is negligible. But note that hashing, unlike a comparator, has to process all characters upfront, which can turn out to be more expensive than the log₂ comparisons of a small `TreeMap`.

If these keywords are unlikely to change, an explicit lookup code, i.e.  a `switch` over invariant properties of the key strings, can be even more efficient. E.g. start with switching over the `length`, if most keywords differ in length, then over a character which is different for most keywords (include `case` labels for uppercase and lowercase variant). Another alternative is a hierarchical lookup structure for these properties.

Comment: Lot of useful informations in this great answer to process.

Comment: Could you explain what the last step in the comparator function does? `if(c1 != c2) return Integer.compare(c1, c2);` Both characters are upper-cased, and when they aren't equal then...?

Comment: @a.ilchinger The contract of the comparator is to return a positive or negative integer, depending on whether the first object is smaller or bigger than the second. The method `Integer.compare(…)` has the same contract, so delegating to it for the first mismatching character makes the order depend on the leftmost character that differs, just like the standard lexicographic order does, except that we use the uppercase character to make it case insensitive. But as said, since this is the secondary order after `comparingInt(CharBuffer::remaining)`, the map’s primary order is by length.